# R studio and Github installation error

Tags: r, github, installation

I am currently trying to install a package from a github repository, `dkahle/ggmap`, using Rstudio. I have installed `devtools` and subsequently used `install_github`. However, I keep getting an `Installation failed: SSL connect` error.

Here is the output on the console log:

```
install.packages("devtools")
> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/lic22/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) trying URL
> 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/devtools_1.13.2.zip'
> Content type 'application/zip' length 440518 bytes (430 KB) downloaded
> 430 KB
> 
> package ‘devtools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> 
> The downloaded binary packages are in
>   C:\Users\"UserFolder"\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpwDCmpm\downloaded_packages



library(devtools)
 install_github("dkahle / ggmap") 

> Installation failed: SSL connect error
```

`

I am currently running windows 10 education edition.

Does anyone know the cause of this? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any more to the error mesage than "SSL connect error" ? It may be a transient issue.

Comment: No unfortunately not, which is why I am having a hard time finding a solution